# Error in ORDER BY clause using CASE WHEN

Tags: sql-server-2016

I'm trying to allow ASC/DESC sort order to be defined by a parameter in a stored procedure.

After lots of research, I found this approach (with simplification):

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
ORDER BY CASE WHEN @reverse = 1 THEN
              MyColumn
         END DESC,
         CASE WHEN @reverse = 0 THEN
              MyColumn
         END ASC
```

However, this code throws the following error:

> Msg 408, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
>   A constant expression was encountered in the ORDER BY list, position 2.

Why is this happening? Clearly MyColumn isn't a constant - it is a column name.

Using SQL Server 2016 in Compatibility Mode 2016 (130)

Thanks

Comment: Your second `CASE` expression is always `NULL`, since the only condition is `WHEN 1 = 0`, and that's always false, and you didn't define an `ELSE`

Comment: @radders Please Check the below solution this will work for you. Just send the filter as string in usp and concatenate it with query and after that you can get the result by executing the new query(With filter) by using EXEC('Query with filter DESC or ASC')

Comment: @Lamak, if you look at the edited OP you will see that the WHEN isn't always NULL - only one of the two of them will be, depending upon the value of the BIT variable.

Comment: @radders yeah, the edited code is absolutely different than the one I commented on

Answer (score 1):

After [some search this line helped me](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/0dc9fa09-7b11-4193-9ce1-619381146119/order-by-a-sort-column-can-include-an-expression-but-the-expression-cannot-resolve-to-a-constant?forum=transactsql) understand more..

> ordering by  an expression  must evaluate to a constant

so  as Lamak pointed out,`1=0` evaluates to false and you didn't define an else condition..so null is undefined and it throws error

to get rid of that try like below

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN 1 = 1 THEN
              MyColumn
         END DESC,
         CASE WHEN 1 = 0 THEN
              col2 else col2--not your column,added this to make example clearer
         END ASC
```

also beware ,expressions in order by must be unique,so your query  won't work(even if it succeeds) and throws different error,you can use ISNULL as well

Comment: But your condition is the same as `ORDER BY MyColumn DESC, MyColumn ASC`, effectively ordering only by `MyColumn DESC`

Comment: I did say I had simplified; the real query looks like the edited version above

Answer (score 0):

The real underlying cause of all this grief is the fact that:

```
ORDER BY MyColumn ASC
```

requires the

```
ASC
```

to be a hard-coded string (like `SELECT, FROM`, etc.) and can't be a **string variable**. ;-((

In order to overcome this limitation,
and the problem caused by trying to use CASE to overcome it,
I have made 95% of the query fill a table-variable,
then I have one of two queries which SELECT from it with the correct ORDER BY clause.