# Using OFFSET and FETCH with the ORDER BY clause and CASE clause together

Tags: sql, sql-order-by, case

New to sql, I am trying to use ORDER BY clause with CASE and OFFSET FETCH together but always getting `Invalid usage of the option NEXT in the FETCH statement.` I want to order by col 1 based on an input and to only limit fetching 10 queries at a time.

I've tried several formats but still get the same error. I've read some other stack overflow articles and the documentation but have been stuck for awhile. Would be grateful for any insight.

`SELECT...`

Option 1.

```
         CASE WHEN desc = 1 THEN col1 DESC END
         CASE WHEN desc != 1 THEN col1 ASC END
         END
         OFFSET 10 ROWS
         FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
```

Option 2.

```
         CASE WHEN desc = 1 THEN col1 DESC END
         CASE WHEN desc != 1 THEN col1 ASC END
         OFFSET 10 ROWS
         FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
```

Option 3.

```
         CASE WHEN desc = 1 THEN col1 DESC 
         OFFSET 10 ROWS
         FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
         END
         CASE WHEN desc != 1 THEN col1 ASC 
         OFFSET 10 ROWS
         FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
         END
```

Option 4.

```
         CASE WHEN desc = 1 THEN col1 DESC
         CASE WHEN desc != 1 THEN col1 ASC
         END
         OFFSET 10 ROWS
         FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: Show us some sample table data and its expected order. (Formatted text, no images.)

Comment: col1 data type?

Comment: Integer data type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DESC` and `ASC` need to go after the `CASE` expression:

```
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN [desc] = 1 THEN col1 END) DESC,
         (CASE WHEN [desc] <> 1 THEN col1 END) ASC
OFFSET 10 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=944376caa7f699d1391af29bc40135e2) is a db<>fiddle showing that this syntax works (in the sense of not generating an error).

I'm not sure exactly what you want to accomplish, but at least the syntax should work.

If `desc` is a column, then it should be surrounded by escape characters.  If it is a variable, then it should be `@desc`.

It would also appear that you are seeing the *last* error.  If you leave off the square braces, the errors messages are:

> Msg 156 Level 15 State 1 Line 3
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'desc'.
>
> Msg 153 Level 15 State 2 Line 5
>   Invalid usage of the option NEXT in the FETCH statement.

Comment: I still get the same error with this syntax, I'm trying to get a set of integers 10 at a time. However there is a filter where I can get them either by desc or asc so I am trying to write a query that does that.

Comment: @EspressoByte . . . I don't know what `desc` is, but it is a SQL keyword.  It probably needs to be escaped.

Comment: desc was just a filler I put in for this post, it is actually a variable that's passed in.  After using your syntax, I get a new error ```A constant expression was encountered in the ORDER BY list, position 1```.  And I've been looking at other posts with this and not sure what they mean by order by must evaluate to a constant? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40633220/error-in-order-by-clause-using-case-when

Comment: @EspressoByte . . . This answers the question that you have asked in this question.  I would suggest that you ask *another* question with more appropriate sample data, desired results, and explanation of what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Since col1 is integer, you can simply do:

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN desc = 1 THEN -col1 ELSE col1 END ASC
OFFSET 10 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: Sorry to clarify, col1 has integer values but passing in the column name is a variable. Would the negative sign affect the variable passed in? I get a ```Invalid operator for data type. Operator equals minus, type equals nvarchar.```